# Gradle Sync Failed..could not find method lintOptions() for argument Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

this is my build.gradle file please help me out ..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.androidhive.info.weplanbeta"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
 }
}
```

these are the dependencies i think i have organized them properly but still its not running

```
dependencies {

   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })

   compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.3.1@aar') {
      transitive = true
   }


   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
   compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
   compile 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:1.0.3'
   compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.9'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
   compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: post complete gradle file

Comment: lint option must be posed under `android{}` component of `gradle`

Comment: complete as in??

Comment: Where is lintOptions written ?

Comment: i have not used the lint option,  oh so whwre we need to write it and how??

Comment: Post your full gradle ,looks like you have written something under wrong tag.

Comment: i have added the method lint but errror still remains

Comment: @DhruvGupta I am not sure but can you change `androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espres‌​so-core:2.2.2', { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' })` to this `androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espres‌​so-core:2.2.2'){ exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }`

Answer (score 2):

You should enable **[lintOptions](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions)**

```
   android {
  ...
  lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
            ignoreWarnings true //false
              }
          }
```

And

```
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
```

Comment: @DhruvGupta set `v7:25.1.0` version .Hope this helps

Comment: @DhruvGupta check brackets

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Could not find method lintOptions() for arguments [build_jjqsdtlufncyzgqdyehrexvx$_run_closure2$_closure4@5016b7e9] on task ':clean' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete........and other errorGradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. and this error showing up

Comment: i have checked the brackets

Comment: @DhruvGupta Make sure all dependencies are using .Remove unwanted

Comment: @DhruvGupta `firebase-auth:9.0.2` too old version .Call `:10.2.1`